# Difference Between かなり～ and 結構～ as Adverbs

Tags: nuances

Is there any difference in meaning between かなりうまい and 結構うまい? How about other usages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

かなり is a little stronger than 結構, i.e., かなり > 結構.

> A はかなりうまい。
>
> B は結構うまい。

In this example, A is better than B.

Also, 結構 can only be used for positive evaluation.

If in daily use, I suggest that you use かなり.

Comment: "結構 can only be used for positive evaluation" is a wrong information.

Comment: Maybe you're objecting to the specific wording, but that general nuance (it is used to express satisfaction and generally not used with negative evaluations) is what is suggested by the description of 結構 in this thesaurus entry. https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/13890/meaning/m0u/%E7%B5%90%E6%A7%8B/